# Как на windows добавить в .gitignore_global папку .idea/?

Tags: git, github

Добрый день, коллеги!

Как на windows добавить в `.gitignore_global` папку `.idea/`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550437/how-to-make-git-ignore-idea-files-created-by-rubymine пробовали?

Comment: у меня локальный .gitignore работает, задача записать .idea/ в глобальный на windows

Comment: Да. Там писали, что возможно `.idea` уже находится в stage гита. Точно `.idea` уже не трекается гитом?

Comment: если убрать из локального `.gitignore` трекается

Comment: А если вот так `**/.idea/`?

Comment: в глобальном или локальном?

Comment: В глобальном файле.

Comment: пока добавил по классике `.idea/`